# Can I import a library write in Kotlin to my android project (uses java)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have to import a library written in Kotlin to my android project. The library needed to import is [here](https://github.com/skedgo/DateTimeRangePicker)

This library is written in Kotlin but I am using java in my project.Is this possible? I have done some research on this topic but I can't find a good document on this.

Comment: Why not just try it and ask questions when you encounter any issues?

Comment: Is there any example for this for reference ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can. Kotlin compiles to Java bytecode so it's completely compatible

Comment: It's not that simple. The library could be using `kotlin-stdlib-jre8` artifact which relies on Java 8.

Comment: that's true, but the library he is pointing out is specifically made for Android, so it doesn't use `kotlin-stdlib-jre8` for sure