# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lkotlin/KotlinPackage

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Try to run a Kotlin project on Android studio (3.6.+) then get this error and project build is not complete. None of kotlin libraries is found even if I create a new project.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: infixsoft.xxxx.xxxx, PID: 28569
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lkotlin/KotlinPackage;
        at infix.imrankst1221.codecanyon.ui.splash.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.kt:30)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "kotlin.KotlinPackage" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/infix.imrankst1221.rocket.web-M3pSn5Zd9TKPdhM0xxH9mA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/infix.imrankst1221.rocket.web-M3pSn5Zd9TKPdhM0xxH9mA==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at infix.imrankst1221.codecanyon.ui.splash.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.kt:30)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: `.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass` enable `multiDexEnabled true`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I  enable that but still the same don't resolve. But if I change PC language another language (Turkish) to English then sometimes resolved.

Comment: `SplashActivity.kt:30` show line no 30

Comment: Here is the code, in case of i remove this then get an error on another kotlin line.

val gradientDrawable = GradientDrawable(
                GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM,
                intArrayOf(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorPrimary),
                        ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorSecondary)))

Comment: Check this answer - maybe it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/59832244/9248201

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 :
Add this in build Gradle ( app level)

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Then Click Scyn Now.

Step 2 :

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Then Click Scyn Now.

Final Step Click Run.